# Storing bits in a file with keys Java - Compression

Tags: java, compression, byte, bit, huffman-code

I have created a compression program in Java using Huffman codes which reads in the bytes from a file and compresses them so as any bytes with a higher frequency are awarded a smaller bit size.

[image]

How do I output these bits to a file so I can import these bits again, along with a key/legend for converting the bits back to their original bytes (decompressing).

[EDIT]

The program can read in the bits fine because they are encoded using huffman trees, I just don't know how I would go about storing them.

Comment: Is your question "How to do file I/O?" or "How do I serialize my huffman encoding?"?

Comment: How should I output the bits so I can input them again in the future for decompression? (inc. key/legend)